# How to run Selenium tests in multiple browsers for cross-browser testing using Java?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver with Java & TestNG framework. I want to use Firefox, IE, Chrome in one single code at a time for doing cross-browser testing. I can only initialize Firefox as

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

but cannot initialize other browsers in the same way. For example:

```
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

gives the error `InternetExplorerDriver cannot be resolved.`

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

gives the error `ChromeDriver cannot be resolved.`

How can I initialize IE and Chrome and execute my tests in all the desired browser ?

Comment: are you using the selenium-server-standalone.jar? If not add it to your classpath and you don't have to add each browser server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For C#

Add

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
```

Create a config file which will contain browser name.
Implement a method for interaction with the config file

And you can use below code for initialize browsers:

```
string browser = GetConfigProperty("browser"); //Get browser name from the config
        switch (browser)
        {
            case "chrome":
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                break;
            case "firefox":
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                break;
            case "InternetExplorer":
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                break;
        }
```

good luck!

Comment: @alexey.chumagin: How to make config? What's the content of config?

Comment: @NazifaChowdhury: As per java convention the import will be as follows: import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

Comment: @Ripon Al Wasim. You can create a xml file. And Parse it how any xml document.

Comment: @Ripon Al Wasim. Browser name is put in section (For example)<BrowserName>chrome</BrowserName>

Answer (score 1):

Create testng.xml having the following content:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Regression Test" verbose="1">  
    <test name="Login_IE">
    <parameter name="browser" value="iexplore"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.gb.test.selenium.login.Login" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Login_FF">
    <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"></parameter>
    <classes>
    <class name="com.gb.test.selenium.login.Login" />
    </classes>
    </test>
<test name="Login_Chrome">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"></parameter>
    <classes>
    <class name="com.gb.test.selenium.login.Login" />
    </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Now write your Java WebDriver code as below:

```
@Parameters({"browser"})
  @BeforeClass
  public void setUp(String browser) {//throws MalformedURLException{
      if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("iexplore")){
          File file = new File("E:\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.29.1\\IEDriverServer.exe");
          System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
          driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

      }
      if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")){
          driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      }
      if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){
          File file = new File("F:\\chromedriver_win_22_0_1203_0b\\chromedriver.exe");//v22
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
      }

      jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(DEFAULT_IMPLICIT_WAIT_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          driver.get("URLOfSite");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For Ruby you can do the following if you want to run your single code in all three browsers one after the other:

```
def all_browsers
  browsers = [:firefox,:ie,:chrome].each do |br|
  $driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for br
  $driver.manage.window.maximize
  $driver.navigate.to("http://google.com")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For Java, since the posters question was asking for a Java answer, [I wrote a complete multi-browser parallel window example](https://github.com/djangofan/WebDriverTestingTemplate/tree/master/parallelwebdriver).