# How to config file for multiple browsers in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, internet-explorer, google-chrome, webdriver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to initialize multiple browsers in WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823150/how-to-initialize-multiple-browsers-in-webdriver)

How I config file for IE and Chrome. driver= new firefoxDriver(); working perfectly but
driver=new InterExploraDriver or driver= new ChromeDriver not working properly.Need some configuration for IE and Chrome. How and where I have to config? What's the necessary code in Java?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. However please be nice with your old question here — http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823150/how-to-initialize-multiple-browsers-in-webdriver

Answer (score 1):

You would need standalone servers for IE and Chrome in order to run your tests on those browsers. They can be found at

http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Download those servers and place the path to the exe files and initialize the drivers as shown below:

IE

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", pathOftheexe);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

You would also need to set the Protected Mode settings for each security zone to be the same value. on IE, choose Tools menu, and click on the Security tab. For each zone, there will be a check box at the bottom of the tab labeled "Enable Protected Mode". Keep this setting same for all zones i.e.  either ON or OFF .

Chrome:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", pathOfexe);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Please refer the following links for details:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

Comment: I am using IEDriverServer.exe for IE. My code is: File file = new File("F:\\Software Download_Ripon\\WebDriver\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.25.2\\IEDriverServer.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(); driver.get("https://www.google.com/"); IE was opened, but the page was directed to "http://localhost:25178/" and the following message was shown on page "This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server." . The google page was not opened

Comment: My chrome code is working well. But an extra tab is opened having the following URL "http://reganam.ourtoolbar.com/welcome/". How can I stop  to open that Reganam tab? Just to share my code: File file = new File("F:\\Software Download_Ripon\\WebDriver\\chromedriver_win_22_0_1203_0b\\chromedriver.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the selenium-server-standalone.jar. Add it to your classpath and you don't have to add each browser server.