# How do I declare a driver as global?

Tags: java, selenium

Here is how I declare firefox driver:

```
public static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

I place the code above outside main and within my class (global)

Here is how I declare chrome driver:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/xxx/xxx/xx");
WebDriver driver  = new ChromeDriver();
```

I place the code above in main

Here is the issue:

I want to make the ChromeDriver as a global but I **NEED** to set the property **before** doing so. But I place the `System.setProperty("xx","xx");` within the main body. Cuz it gives error when placed outside.

Here is a user trying to do the same thing as me. Trying to run different browsers using the same driver : [How to run Selenium tests in multiple browsers for cross-browser testing using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823150/how-to-initialize-multiple-browsers-in-selenium-webdriver-a-k-a-selenium-2-usi)

The answer is involves declaring the driver in the main body and not as a constant before.

**My issue:** All functions need driver declaration from before. Calling functions which use `driver`. If I declare `driver` in main, I need to continuously pass it as a parameter to all the functions. I do not wish to do that. Here is an example function

```
 public static void a(){

 driver.findElement(By.id("hi"));

}
```

Comment: Why do you need to make it a global in the first place?

Comment: Because ALL functions depend on it. They all have "driver" in them. They ALL will completely break if I don't make it global.

Comment: You can always pass it to different classes in their constructors for instance and use it as a class variable. Java doesn't really support global variables anyway, a variable is always in the scope of some class or method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like:

```
class SomeTest {

    static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("key", "value");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    public static void a() {

        driver.findElement(By.id("hi"));

    }
}
```

Comment: ...and you were correct! I didn't even think about just initializing Webdriver. I was initializing ChromeDriver. Thanks buddy :)

Comment: remember @OctavianRox, don't think of this as a "global" variable.  Java doesn't have those.  It's all maintained with Scope.  In this case, `driver` will be in the scope of the class, and is a `field`.  The field is accessible throughout the class.

Comment: Also remember not to run parallel tests if you are going for a static driver.

Comment: @NeuronB I don't know if I would completely agree with that. If you use Maven surefire-plugin (or failsafe-plugin), and you spawn your tests into forks rather than threads, then using a static driver is still safe. It depends on your use case.