# Chrome instead of firefox, element not found

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm starting to use selenium and have some problems.

here is my code (c#):

```
namespace Selenium1
{
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    FirefoxDriver firefox;

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        firefox = new FirefoxDriver();
        firefox.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
        firefox.FindElement(By.Id("gbqfq")).SendKeys("Google");
        firefox.FindElement(By.Id("gbqfq")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        firefox.Quit();
    }
}
}
```

but instead of opening firefox it is opening **chrome** and invoking error:

```
Test method Selenium1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"gbqfq"}
```

where is my mistake?

thx.

Comment: Have you added Firefox plugin?

Comment: Looks strange issue...which is your default browser?

Answer (score 0):

have a look here:
[How to run Selenium tests in multiple browsers for cross-browser testing using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823150/how-to-initialize-multiple-browsers-in-selenium-webdriver-a-k-a-selenium-2-usi)

and here
http://www.widecodes.com/7QJyWVUWVX/how-to-initialize-a-c-selenium-webdriver-test-to-pass-in-different-browser-types.html